# How to get rid of "Key" in S3 put event in Lambda test event?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to put my CSV file from S3 to DynamoDB through the Lambda function. In the first stage, I was uploading my .csv file manually in S3 manually. When uploading the file manually, I know the name of the file, and I put this file name as a key in the test event and it works file.
[image: S3 put event]

I want to automate things because my .csv files are automatically generated in the S3 and I don't know what will be the name of the next file. Someone suggested me to create trigger in S3 that will invoke your Lambda on every file generation. The only issue I am dealing with is what to put in the test event at the place of "key", where we are supposed to put a file name whose data we want to fetch from S3.
[image: What to put here]

I don't have a file name now. Following is the Lambda code:

```
import json 
import boto3 

s3_client = boto3.client("s3") 
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
student_table = dynamodb.Table('AgentMetrics')
 
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    source_bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    
    file_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket_name,Key=file_name)
    print("file_object :",file_object)
    
    file_content = file_object['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")
    print("file_content :",file_content)
    
    students = file_content.split("\n")
    print("students :",students)
    
    for student in students:
        data = student.split(",")
        try:
            student_table.put_item(
            Item = {
                "Agent" : data[0],
                "StartInterval" : data[1],
                "EndInterval" : data[2],
                "Agent idle time" : data[3],
                "Agent on contact time" : data[4],
                "Nonproductive time" : data[5],
                "Online time" : data[6],
                "Lunch Break time" : data[7],
                "Service level 120 seconds" : data[8],
                "After contact work time" : data[9],
                "Contacts handled" : data[10],
                "Contacts queued" : data[11]
           } )
        except Exception as e:
            print("File Completed")
```

The error I am facing is  ["errorMessage": "An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.",
"errorType": "NoSuchKey",]

[image: Error]

Kindly help me here, I am getting frustrated because of this issue. I would really appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Please don't post your JSON as screenshots, but properly formatted code blocks. Also you haven't explained what is the issue with the code? What errors do you get?

Comment: The test event is an event to test the lambda, nothing more.  Pick some existing file and use that in the test event, it has no bearing on what the lambda sees in the event when it's executed as part of a trigger with real data.

Comment: @Marcin I have edited the question and added the error that i am facing, can you please tell me what's the error.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in your question you have to add trigger to S3 bucket on action POST, PUT OR DELETE whichever action need to track.
Here is more details :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

1. Select Lambda either python or nodeJs whichever you prefer from blueprint option
2. Then select S3 bucket and action like PUT, POST OR DELETE or all.
3. Write your above code make entry in db in this lambda.

Answer (score 0):

The "Test Event" you are using is an example of a message that Amazon S3 will send to your Lambda function when a new object is created in the bucket.

When S3 triggers your AWS Lambda function, it will provide details of the object that trigger the event. Your program will then use the event supplied by S3. It will *not* use your Test Event.

One more thing...

It is possible that the Lambda function will be triggered with **more than one object** being passed via the `event`. Your function should be able to handle this happening. You can do this by adding a `for` loop:

```py
import urllib
...

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    for record in event['Records']:

        source_bucket_name = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        file_name = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(record['s3']['object']['key'])
        ...
```

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are saying. What's the problem then? I have added the error screenshot that i an facing. Can you check and tell me what fixes are needed?

Comment: @RehanCH When you receive that error message, how are you triggering the function? Are you simply uploading a file to S3, which automatically triggers the Lambda function to run? One possibility is that the Key has strange characters. If so, you can use `urllib.parse.unquote_plus` as shown in my example above. You can debug it by printing the Bucket name and Key, to figure out what's happening.